# JAXB -EclipseLink MOXy- Nested Composite objects not getting marshalled correctly

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

The mapping java classes are generated from the below schema usign XJC tool.
The XML schema is:

```
 <xs:complexType name="configurations">
     <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="configuration" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
         <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="variation" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>                                
             <xs:attribute name="charValueName" type="LimitedString30" />             
             <xs:attribute name="charValueDesc" type="LimitedString40" />
             <xs:attribute type="xs:decimal" name="price" />        
             <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="pricingUnit" />
            </xs:complexType>
           </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
         <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="charName" />
       </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
 </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>***
```

And the marshalled XML using JAXB is:

```
  <configurations>
  <configuration charName="XYZ">
   <variation>Configurations$Configuration$Variation@44d8783e</variation>
   <variation>Configurations$Configuration$Variation@5fbe51c1</variation>
 </configuration>
 </configurations>
```

If you look at the 'variation' element above, it doesn't have any attributes like 'charValueName', 'charValueDesc' etc marshalled. Any idea why? Is there any limitation on the depth of nested elements, with JAXB?

Comment: Which implementation and version of JAXB are you using?

Comment: Blaise, I'm using JAXB 2.0.

Comment: JAXB 2.0 is the specificaction version (see:  http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222).  There are implementation such as the RI (http://jaxb.java.net/) and EclipseLink MOXy (http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php).  You can call `getClass()` on the `JAXBContext` to find out the provider, determining the version depends on the provider.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read ur question completely. We are using Moxy,(javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory).

Comment: Could you tell me the result of `System.out.println(org.eclipse.persistence.Version.getVersion());`?  BTW - I'm the MOXy lead.

Comment: Nice to meet you, Blaise. The version is 2.3.1. Even the RI implementation is behaving the same way.

Comment: Are you able to upgrade your version of EclipseLink (current version is 2.5.0) or do you need to get this to work on EclipseLink 2.3.1?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36276/discussion-between-blaise-doughan-and-krs)

Comment: Are you able to join the chat root?

Comment: It works fine with JAXB RI. It solves my purpose for now. Thanks, Blaise. BTW, is the issue specific to MOXy and is it resolved in 2.5.0 version?

Comment: It had to do with MOXy not picking up a referenced class automatically (you could supply it when creating the `JAXBContext` yourself).  I believe the issue was fixed in EclipseLink 2.3.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group

This problem can occur in MOXy if it is unaware of the class being marshalled.  The object ends up getting marshalled based on its `toString()` method.  You identified that you are using EclipseLink 2.3.1 and I believe you are hitting the following bug that was fixed in EclipseLink 2.3.2:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/360860

As of today (August 26, 2013) the current version of EclipseLink is 2.5.0 which can be downloaded from the following location:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/